# xUnit.net will not run Dispose if test is stopped manually

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, resharper, xunit.net

I have a Selenium test framework that I've been building and I'm having difficulty getting `Driver.Quit()` to run if the test is stopped manually.

This is a highly dumbed-down version of my framework, but it should contain all the important elements:

```
public class DriverClass : IDisposable
{
    public static IWebDriver Driver;

    public DriverClass()
    {
         Driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    public Dispose()
    {
         Driver.Quit();
         Debug.WriteLine("The driver has quit");
    }
}

// Using Collection fixtures for elements to be shared
// by all Selenium tests such as the web driver.
[CollectionDefinition("Selenium Tests")]
public class SeleniumTestCollection : ICollectionFixture<DriverClass>
{
}

public AssistantDriverClass : DriverClass
{
     public static void DoSomething()
     {
         Driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("someClass")).Click(); // Just an example
     }

     public static void Logout()
     {
         Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("localhost/#/logout");
     }
}

// Using class fixtures for common test elements 
// and to log out at the end of the test class
public class TestClassFixture : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        AssistantDriverClass.Logout()
    }
}

[Collection("Selenium Tests")]
public class TestClass : IClassFixture<TestClassFixture>
{
    [Fact]
    public void DoAThing()
    {
        AssistantDriverClass.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

When I let the tests complete on their own, the browser and driver are stopped and "The driver has quit" is output.

When I stop the tests manually in VS2017 (by pressing the stop button), the driver and browser remain open and I need to close them manually. I'd like if these both stopped. "The driver has quit" is not output in this case.

This is a pretty common scenario to stop the test manually while I'm writing them and proving them out, so I'd like to have `Driver.Quit()` run when the process is halted.

I've tried using `void OnStop()` override with no success in my DriverClass.

I suspect the use of a static Driver and my extending the class in `AssistantDriverClass` has something to do with it, but I'm not quite willing to let go of that design unless I absolutely have to. This design makes it pretty easy to make abstractions in the framework.

Using:

- Selenium.Firefox.WebDriver (0.19.1) - NuGet
- Selenium.Support (3.8.0) - NuGet
- Visual Studio 2017 15.4.4
- ReSharper 2017.2.2

Comment: Pretty sure (but it's ultimately a guess...) VS kills the runner in such a way that the test framework doesn't get to hook

Comment: I guess the question is how to overcome that? That seems like a pretty fundamental issue with the VS test runner.

Comment: Always establish preconditions, don't worry about guaranteeing postconditions in general is a good strategy for testing in general; Don't have any other ideas

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this ?

Comment: Asked again in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65479735/xunit-dispose-method-on-collection-fixture-class-not-being-called-when-test-is  which also has no answers.