# xUnit - Dispose method on Collection Fixture class not being called when test is cancelled

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit, dispose

I have a CollectionFixture where I create a new resource on Azure to run my tests and I delete that resource on Dispose method, but when I cancel some test then the Dispose method is not called and then this resource is not being deleted. How can I handle with that?

Obs.: I'm using xunit version 2.4.1 and xunit.runner.visualstudio version 2.4.3

**Edit: Adding some code as Fabio requested**

I have a simple FixtureCollection:

```
[CollectionDefinition(nameof(EventBusServiceBusCollection))]
public class EventBusServiceBusCollection : ICollectionFixture<EventBusServiceBusFixture> { }
```

And my EventBusServiceBusFixture class is like that

```
public class EventBusServiceBusFixture : IDisposable
{
    public EventBusServiceBusFixture()
    {
        //...
        // Create a queue on Azure Service Bus
        CreateQueueAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }        

    public void Dispose()
    {
        //...
        // Delete the queue from Azure Service Bus
        DeleteQueueAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```

So I create a new Azure Service Bus Queue when the tests start and delete it when it finishes. It's working perfectly, the problem it's when I cancel the tests because the Dispose method is not being called

Comment: Can you show some code? How you define collection fixture and dispose method?

Comment: At first I didn't put any code in because it's a simple scenario, but thanks for the comment. I edited the question, check and tell me if it's better @Fabio

Comment: I've got the same problem, too bad nobody has answered.

Comment: Seems that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48197454/xunit-net-will-not-run-dispose-if-test-is-stopped-manually is basically the same problem.